# Create map like data structure

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this product model:

```
export class Product {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    price: number;
    url: string;
    description: string;

    constructor() {
        this.id = 1;
        this.name = '';
        this.price = 0.0;
        this.url = '';
        this.description = '';
    }
}
```

I would like to create a map like a data structure where I can use the Product id as a key and with that, I can receive the structure that has the product itself and the quantity.

In Java that would be:

```
Map<Integer, Pair<Product, Integer>> = new HashMap<>();
```

How do I implement it using TypeScript?

Comment: It's `new Map<number, [Product, number]>()` in TypeScript

Comment: @mcanzerini No, you don't want an array here, if the product ids are not zero-based and continuous indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Record`:

```
type ProductMap = Record<number, {product: Product, quantity: number}>;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
type ProductMap = Map<number, {product: Product, quantity: number}>

const myProductMap : ProductMap = new Map();

// or use it directly
const myProductMap2 = new Map<number, {product: Product, quantity: number}>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom dictionary like this:

```
interface Map<T> {
    [Key: number]: KeyValuePair<T,number>;
}

interface KeyValuePair<T, Y> {
    key: T;
    value: Y;
}

var somedata: Map<Product> = {...};
```